# User Access Level in Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to put user access level in My Java Web Application.But even I enter the correct username and password which I have declare in the tomcat-user.xml file It is not working. It gong to loginerror page. Basic Authentication Method also Not Accepting Correct Username and password.

This tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

-->
<role rolename=”Admin”/>
<role rolename=”Member”/>
<role rolename=”Doctor”/>
<role rolename=”Guest”/>
<user username=”sirojan” password=”sirojan” roles=”Admin” />
<user username=”ram” password=”ram123” roles=”Member” />
<user username=”vithu” password=”newbie” roles=”Guest” />
</tomcat-users>
```

This is a part of server.xml file

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">


    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" /> 

        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
<!-- <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" /> -->
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/><!--
-->      </Realm>
```

This is My a  part of web.xml file

```
<security-role> 
        <role-name>Admin</role-name> 
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Member</role-name> 
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Guest</role-name> 
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Doctor</role-name> 
    </security-role>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login2.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AdminTasks</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/Department.jsp</url-pattern>

            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
            <role-name>Member</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

    </security-constraint>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/notFoundError.jsp</location>
    </error-page> 

</web-app>
```

Did I anything wrong??. If you need further pl comment it. Can you please give the solutions for that??

Comment: Remove the smart quotes - `<role rolename=”Admin”/>`. It *must* be  `<role rolename="Admin"/>`

Comment: I change according to your suggestion, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

first check whether the existing roles are working for you or not .

for that u need to uncomment the roles in tomcat-users.xml

if they are working ,and u r able to login in tomcat console, then problem is ur syntax ,

if they are not working then u need to go with the error page documentation and check what u r doing is correct or not because this is kind of easy and works every time for me .

Comment: u can check it using Tomcat manager , if ur able to login using the existing roles than it is working